# Navigating to ASP.NET Core app results in "HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure" ErrorCode 0x80004005 : 1

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1.4 ASP.NET MVC app hosted in IIS (Win 10 OS).

Each time I attempt to access the site in a browser I see this error:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Here is the .NET Core info for my machine:

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
>   Version:   2.1.402
>   Commit:    3599f217f4
>
> > Runtime Environment:
> >     OS Name:     Windows
> >     OS Version:  10.0.17134
> >     OS Platform: Windows
> >     RID:         win10-x64
> >     Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\
>
> Host (useful for support):
>   Version: 2.1.4
>   Commit:  85255dde3e
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>
> 2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>                                                                                              .NET Core runtimes installed:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]         Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

In the Event Log the following error is logged:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MOTORFINANCE' with physical root
>   'C:\src\FooSiteProject\Website-FooSite\FooSite\' failed to start
>   process with commandline 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
>   .\FooSite.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 1.

I'm struggling to find any references to that error code combination `0x80004005 : 1`. Is there anyone who can help me out please?

EDIT:

The identity which the app pool runs under, `NETWORK SERVICE`, does have the required permissions set against the folder where the ASP.NET Core app lives.

EDIT:
I earlier installed various .NET Core installers:

- `aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.4-win-x64`
- `dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-win-gs-x64`
- `dotnet-runtime-2.1.4-win-x64`

I executed the `iisreset` command, but that did not fix the issue. So in response to a comment below, I rebooted the laptop and navigated to the site again. I got the same result, with the same error log in `Event Log`.

In case this helps, here is a snippet from the `web.config` relating to `aspnetcore`

`<handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\Foo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#app-startup-errors

Comment: Cheers for the link. When I get time, I will go through those steps as there is stuff in there I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

There's some exception being thrown at startup, which is preventing your app from successfully starting. Open a command prompt changed to the directory of your published project, and then run `dotnet ProjectName.dll`. In the console window, you'll be able to see the stack trace for the exception.

Comment: Ahhh, right - executing that command has started the site, listening on port `localhost:5001`. I can navigate to the site, though the css and js ism issing, but that could be a webpack thing. At least I can view the page without an error.

Comment: If the app runs in the console, but you're still getting errors in with IIS, then ensure that you've installed the hosting bundle on the server *and* either restarted the server completely afterwards or at least restarted the IIS web service (`iisreset` is not enough). See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I know I might get shot down in flames for this question, but do I need to install the hosting installers for both 32bit and 64bit? I tihkn I may have earlier installed `dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win.exe` and then today I ran `dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win.exe`. Wasn't sure if that was a mistake.

Comment: Install based on the architecture of your server. If the server is 64-bit, then install the 64-bit version. You can run 32-bit with that, but not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify my previous comment - which you have answered, I meant to say I ran `dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win-x64.exe` earlier today.

Comment: Remember, you'll need to restart the server after installing.

Comment: Had same problem, it was a typo in my json application config ! Thanks for sharing this answer

Answer (score 0):

I had not installed `Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core`:

[image]

After installing and rebooting, my site is now alive and well :)